# Same JUnit tests working in Ant but not in Maven

Tags: unit-testing, maven, testing, ant, junit

I'm with a very strange problem and would like to understand it.

Well, the problem is that some of my JUnit tests crashed when I tried to run Maven Test, but in Ant or Eclipse's plugin it works perfectly.

Debugging one of the unit tests I discovered the problem: One boolean attibute into a mock class, setted as "false" explicitly, was always "true" when I ran it into Maven. This occurred only with one method annotated with @Test.

I guess that one of the others methods were changing the value of my attribute, like the class was executed in a different order or something like that... I don't know.

I solved it seeting the variable to "false" again into my method, ensuring  the value that I wanted.

Somebody knows why this occurs??

Thanks!

**Maven version:** 3.0.4

```
@After
public void limpa() {
  Mockit.restoreAllOriginalDefinitions();
}

@Test
public void testWithError() throws Exception {
    Mockit.redefineMethods(MyObject.class, MyObjectMock.class);
    MyOtherObject myOtherObject = createMyOtherObject();
    MyObjectMock.hasRules = false;
    try {
        myService.executeServiceA(myOtherObject);
        Assert.fail("Can't get here. Should throw as exception.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Exception  ", "You can't do this beacause of ...", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My mock:

```
public class MyObjectMock{

    //Others attibutes  
    (...)
    public static boolean hasRules = false;

    //Setters and getters
    (...)
}
```

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
       <jmockit.version>0.0.1</jmockit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/junit</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java/selenium</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Need Java 5, which is the default since v2.3 of the maven-compiler-plugin. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/mockit/jmockit/${jmockit.version}/jmockit-${jmockit.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>140</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0-oracle-thin-extras</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-betwixt</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-betwixt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.fckeditor</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>${jmockit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>atg.taglib.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jfreechart-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jodreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java-client-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
            <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Show your code and Ant / Maven scripts.

Comment: Different variables being used by Ant and Maven? Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: Also show your directory structure.  Are test classes in the correct location?

Comment: Ditto @carlspring -- it'd be good to see the code. You're probably right about it being an order problem -- when I've seen something like this, it's usually been because the test (explicitly or implicitly) relies on some static data that's being modified by another class. Also, depending on the mock framework, it may not be safe to share mocks between tests -- try initializing the mock locally in the test method, or in a `@Before` method, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidMoles You are right. My attribute it's static! So the Ant just execute the method in a random different order if compared with Maven? I eddited the post with my code.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot  
They are into "src/test/java/junit

Comment: Please full pom otherwise it's impossible to help. Are you using JUnit 4? Which Maven version? Maven-surefire version? etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise done!
I'm using Maven 3.0.4

Comment: @PimentaDev. That's right. In general, you shouldn't count on tests executing in a certain order. See my answer below for a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't count on Ant and Maven to execute tests in the same order. If tests have interdependencies, it's also easy to get into situations where tests pass when run individually, but fail when run through Ant/Maven, or vice versa; or where they pass only if some other tests are run first, or similar.

The best thing to do is make sure tests aren't dependent on each other. If a test does have to modify static data for some reason, you should make sure it resets the static data after it runs, so each test starts fresh. For example:

```java
public class NoRulesTest {

    private static boolean oldRulesVal;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void NoRulesSetup() {
        oldRulesVal = MyObjectMock.hasRules;
        MyObjectMock.hasRules = false;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void NoRulesTeardown() {
        MyObjectMock.hasRules = oldRulesVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice explanation! Thanks a lot!  
But just one more question, David Moles. My method @Before method shouldn't do this with the following command?  
    
    "Mockit.restoreAllOriginalDefinitions();"

Comment: I'm not really familiar with JMockit (I prefer [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito)), but looking at the Javadoc for `restoreAllOriginalDefinitions()`, it looks like it won't affect `MyObjectMock` -- all it will do is make `MyObject` use its own methods again instead of the mock methods. Still maybe a good idea, if you have to have mocks hanging around between tests, but possibly not directly connected to your problem.

Comment: Thanks again!  
Actually my @ Before method it isn't necessary at all.  
Take a look:  

"In practice, this method **should only be used if all mocked classes needs to be restored in the middle of some test**. Otherwise, it is unnecessary because **JMockit will automatically restore all classes mocked by a test at the end of that test**, as well as all classes mocked for the test class as a whole (eg, in a @ BeforeClass JUnit method) before the first test in the next test class is executed."